# Weakly convergent sequence with a strongly convergence subsequence

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence in a Hilbert Space, which converges weakly to some limit, and it has a subsequence which converges strongly to that same limit. Does this imply the sequence is strongly convergent? I would appreciate if someone could show me a proof / counterexample. Thank you :)

Comment: No. Say $x_n\to0$ weakly but $||x_n||\not\to0$. Consider the sequence $x_1,0,x_2,0,\dots$.